# Writing a chdir command in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, directory

I want to write my own cd command in Linux. The reason? I want to be able to add certain features, like having other options to the command.

But since child processes can't affect parent processes, I'm having trouble getting this to work, since, once the program exits, it goes back to the directory it was in before you ran the command.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: `cd` is a built-in, not a program, for precisely that reason.

Comment: Good thing is Linux is open source. If you wish you can modify a shell like bash to modify the behavior of the shell.

Comment: Well, it isn't just for me. I'd like to be able to distribute this to people using standard Linux distros. Is it possible to use in-line Assembly to modify the piece of memory where the current directory is stored, or anything like that?

Comment: @user2242700 You can distribute it ... as your own shell.  But what types of "extra features" are you thinking you want to add?

Comment: One feature is I'd like for it to be able to go as close to the directory as possible if the full path doesn't exist. Stuff like that.

Comment: Most shells have tab-complete features ... if a path doesn't exist, you won't be able to have it complete it.  But you could write a simple shell script - and alias it to `cd` - to do that if you really wanted it (though, I think you'll find it won't be as useful as you might think).

Comment: Well, a mkdir variant I also want to do would be actually creating the full path if it doesn't exist (rather than having to create each parent directory at a time). I think that would be useful. But I'd like it to automatically change to that directory once it's created, so there's the same problem there.

Comment: You might want to take a look at shell scripts; `fpne=/full/path/to/some/dir/that/doesnt/exist && mkdir -p ${pfne} && cd ${fpne}` <- sets path you want to create to variable `fpne`, creates it if it doesn't exist then `cd`'s to it .. as another user said you could make this a shell script then alias it to what you want...is this kind of what you're looking for?

Comment: Maybe switching to [zsh](http://zsh.org/) might help

Comment: With `zsh` you just need to add a [chpwd](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Hook-Functions) hook function

Comment: txtechhelp: Yeah, that is about what I want, but bash scripts also return me to the directory I was in before once they finish executing.

Comment: You may want to have [bash shell functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html) (but I still believe `zsh` is more convenient for your needs).